# What is the story of Dhruva Tara (North Star)?

Tags: belief

The *Dhruva Tara* (North Star) is believed to be a holy star in Hinduism. What is the story behind it?

Comment: hehe, a nakshatra is not a star.

Comment: @AwalGarg not sure.. google is stating both as star and constellation :|

Comment: Forget Google... he has yet to get a treatment. It is _tara_, _Dhruv *Tara*_...

Comment: As far as my grandparents explained me the story, it is said that druva stood up on one leg chanting god names for years, seeing the dedication and devotion of the kid, god made him a star...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  [kidsgen.com](http://www.kidsgen.com/fables_and_fairytales/indian_mythology_stories/brave_dhruva.htm):-

> King Uttanpada had two wives. His first wife, Sunity, was the daughter
>   of a tribal chief. His second wife, Suruchi, was the daughter of a
>   rich king. Sunity had a son named Dhruva and Suruchi's son was named
>   Uttam. Dhruva was the elder of the two, so it was his right to become
>   the next king.
>
> But Suruchi was very selfish; she hated her stepson Dhruva and wanted
>   her son Uttam to be the ruler. Uttanpada loved Suruchi more than
>   Sunity because she was beautiful. Under her influence, he ordered
>   Sunity and Dhruva to leave the palace.
>
> Mother and son started living in a small hut near the forest. Sunity
>   told Dhruva stories about God and Dhruva always thought about God.
>
> One day, Dhruva went to the palace and saw Uttam sitting on his
>   father's lap. But when Dhruva tried to do the same, Suruchi stopped
>   him and said, "There is no place for you on your father's lap. Only my
>   son can sit on his lap." Dhruva looked at his father hoping that he
>   would stop Suruchi and take him on his lap. But his father did not say
>   anything and ignored him.
>
> Deeply hurt, Dhruva returned to his mother. Weeping bitterly he asked
>   her why he had no place on his father's lap and why they had no place
>   in the palace. Brave DhruvaSunity had no answer to her son's
>   questions. Dhruva said, "You told me that God is good, he helps those
>   who pray to him. I will go and find God, he will certainly give me my
>   place." Dhruva decided to go to the forest and pray until God appeared
>   before him. In the forest, he met Narada Muni, who was worried that a
>   five-year-old boy like him would face many difficulties in the forest.
>   He warned Dhruva that wild animals could eat him up. But Dhruva was
>   determined to find Lord Vishnu. Impressed by his determination, Narada
>   taught him how to survive in the forest. He also taught him the mantra
>   "Om Namo Bhagavathe Vasudevaya' by chanting which he could please Lord
>   Vishnu.
>
> For many months, Dhruva prayed in the forest, and faced many
>   difficulties. He even stopped eating. With every breath, he chanted
>   the mantra in praise of God. Finally, Lord Vishnu was pleased with his
>   determination and appeared before him. He not only granted Dhruva a
>   place on his father's lap, but also a permanent place in the sky after
>   his death.

Some variation of the story say that Dhruva declined the boon but Lord Vishnu asked him again and again and then he asked for the devine place equal to top of the world, that's why he got boon of become "Druva Tara" after death and even Saptarishi revolves around him. Similar story present [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=zhIbyxoxHMgC&pg=PA41&dq=dhruva%20tara&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fgu1U9nJFY7d8AW5hoGQCQ&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dhruva%20tara&f=false).

Even as per believes his mother also got divine place in swarga and his father also accepted him and he became good king in his life and became star after death.

Some believes say that the story of becoming star after death is also inspired by this story.